# Как подключиться к серверу, запущенному на localhost по внешнему ip

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер

В общем развернут сервер, к которому можно подключиться по http://localhost:3000, пытаюсь подключиться по внешнему ip [http://ip_адресс:3000](http://ip_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81:3000), но ничего не выходит, первый раз этим занимаюсь, не могу вдуплить

Comment: Почему такой номер порта?

Comment: в документации к серверу написан такой, видимо разработчик так решил

Comment: Обычно 80 http, а 3000 - 3000/UDP Distributed Interactive Simulation (DIS), modifiable default

Comment: наберите `real ip`  того компьютера на котором лежит локальный сервер, если порт не стандартный (`80`), то и порт то же после `ip`.

Comment: убедится в каких нибудь настройках сервера, что он слушает на всех ip, а не только на 127.0.0.1 и посмотреть не закрыт ли порт в фаерволе. Ну и разумеется убедится что набираемый ip адрес действительно присутствует на одном из сетевых интерфейсов сервера

Comment: Система какая? Я же правильно понимаю, что у вас сервер запущен просто на домашнем компьютере?

Comment: Нет, запущенно на удаленном компьюетере с Ubuntu 16.04, с которым я работаю по ssh.  Открыл порт командой "$ ufw allow 3000", далее проверяю "$ netstat -tulpn", выводит "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN", но все равно не работает, пытаюсь подключиться со своего домашнего, но не выходит